# DELETE a row - Sql C#

Tags: c#, mysql

Hello I want to delete a  row from my table , I have 3 tables for Recipe , Ingredient and i'm using the 3rd table to combine the Recipe and Ingredient tables,

my question I can add a row but I don't know how to delete a row  I really dont have an idea how to do it .

the code down plz help ^^"

```
private void btnAddToRecpie_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string query = "INSERT INTO RecpieIngredient VALUES (@RecpieId,@IngredientId)";

        using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (SqlCommand cmnd = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
        {
            connection.Open();
            cmnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RecpieId", lstRecpie.SelectedValue);
            cmnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IngredientId",lstAllIngredient.SelectedValue);
            cmnd.ExecuteScalar();
        }
        PopulateRecpie();
    }

    private void butToDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string query = "DELETE FROM  RecpieIngredient WHERE (@RecpieId , @IngredientId)=@RecpieId , @IngredientId ";

      //  a.Name FROM Ingredient a INNER JOIN RecpieIngredient x ON a.Id = x.IngredientId INNER JOIN Recpie m ON m.Id=x.RecpieId WHERE m.Id=" + index;
        using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (SqlCommand cmnd = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
        {
            connection.Open();

            cmnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RecpieId", lstRecpie.SelectedValue);
            cmnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IngredientId", lstAllIngredient.SelectedValue);

            cmnd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
        PopulateRecpie();
    }
```

Comment: Please search any SQL tutorial on how to write a DELETE statement

Comment: first learn from any tutorial, it will save your time and sometimes even life.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
INSERT INTO RecpieIngredient VALUES (@RecpieId,@IngredientId)
```

Is really shorthand for:

```
INSERT INTO RecpieIngredient (RecpieId, IngredientId) VALUES (@RecpieId, @IngredientId)
```

The `DELETE` statement does not have such a shorthand variant, and requires you to mention the column names explicitly:

```
DELETE FROM RecpieIngredient WHERE RecpieId = @RecpieId AND IngredientId = @IngredientId
```

You came pretty close in fixing the problem yourself though :)

Comment: thanks for the info and  it works ^^ ,but still some problems ill try to fix it ,

Answer (score 0):

You delete statement is wrong. It should be

```
string query = "DELETE FROM RecpieIngredient 
                         WHERE RecpieId = @RecpieId 
                         AND IngredientId = @IngredientId";
```